# Windows phone 8.1 camera preview black edge on rotation

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using video preview on windows phone 8.1 to take pictures. Without rotation, preview don't have black margin edge. After 90 degrees rotation stripes appears on capture element.

Here are my screenshots and XAML, c# code.

**XAML**

```
CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreview" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="27,158,10,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

**C#**

```
    public async void preview()
    {
        DeviceInformationCollection webcamList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

        DeviceInformation backWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
                                        where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null
                                        && webcam.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back
                                        select webcam).FirstOrDefault();
         newCapture = new MediaCapture();          
        await newCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            VideoDeviceId = backWebcam.Id,
            AudioDeviceId = "",
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview
        });                 
        await newCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        newCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
    }
```

**Pictures With rotation**

[image]

**Without rotation**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation as it will add letterboxing to your stream. Instead, use the SetPreviewRotationAsync method from the [Camera Starter Kit UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) from the [Microsoft GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). If you take a close look at it, you'll get a much better idea for how to handle rotation of the camera.

Mainly, it comes down to this:

```
    // Rotation metadata to apply to the preview stream and recorded videos (MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION)
    // Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868174.aspx
    private static readonly Guid RotationKey = new Guid("C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1");

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current orientation of the UI in relation to the device (when AutoRotationPreferences cannot be honored) and applies a corrective rotation to the preview
    /// </summary>
    private async Task SetPreviewRotationAsync(int rotationDegrees)
    {
        // Add rotation metadata to the preview stream to make sure the aspect ratio / dimensions match when rendering and getting preview frames
        var props = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
        props.Properties.Add(RotationKey, rotationDegrees);
        await _mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, props, null);
    }
```

But this is just part of the code. You should have a look at [the full file](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs) (if not the full sample) to get a better understanding of how it works.